# What does the print function actually do other than displaying it?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

The print function did something more than expected and this behavior changes from language to language. Please look at the given code.

Python 3 code:

```
n=print("Interesting")
print(n)
```

Output:

```
Interesting
None
```

---

C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n = printf("Interesting");
    printf("\n%d",n);

}
```

Output:

```
Interesting
11
```

---

I expected the output to be some kind of error but instead both the languages handle it differently. Please explain why this happens and is the print function capable of doing something else other than just displaying?

Comment: In Python every function returns something, at least `None`.

Comment: You could check the references to see what each function is doing: [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). It's also unclear why you'd expect those two very different functions from two distinct languages return the same thing.

Comment: Comparing two functions with similar names of two different programming language makes no sense.

Comment: In C, [`printf()` can change a variable](https://ideone.com/xkyfVT): `int n = -42; printf("foo%nbar\n", &n); printf("new n is %d\n", n);`

Comment: Why would you expect an error? And why would you expect different languages to have same behaviour for functions that don't even have identical name?

Comment: In English, *bald* means having no hair.  In German, *bald* means "soon".  Why the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`print` and `printf` are functions that can have a return value. In Python, `print` simply returns `None`.

In C, the signature of `printf` is `int printf( const char* format, ... );`. It returns an integer equal to the number of characters output. A negative return value indicates that an error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Each language will have a different role for the **print** function.

In **Python 3.0 and beyond**, it is a fully fleshed out **built-in function**.    It has many more roles than is common for a lower-level language like **C**.  See https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html

In Python, there are 3 main uses for the **print()** built-in function.

1) Flexible debug tool:

```
def myfunc(var):
    ''' This function returns the square of a number. '''
    varsquare = var * var  
    print("function steps:", var, varsquare)
    return varsquare
result = myfunc(5):
print("input=", 5, "output=", result)

### sample outputs:
> function steps: 5 25
> input= 5 output= 25
```

2) Flexible python module doc string exploration tool: 
 https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/python-docstrings:

```
# Three different ways to "print" an object's documentation string.

# Print a local function's docstring.
print myfunc.__doc__
# output: 
> This function returns the square of a number.

# Print the docstrings of an imported module and its class.
import mymodule   
print mymodule.__doc__
print mymodule.MyClass.__doc__

##### Example mymodule.py file.  #########
"""
Assuming this is file mymodule.py, then this string, being the
first statement in the file, will become the "mymodule" module's
docstring when the file is imported.
"""

class MyClass(object):
    """The class's docstring"""

def my_method(self):
    """The method's docstring"""

def my_function():
    """The function's docstring"""
```

3) During development, object inspection role:

```
import numpy as np
print(np)

# output:
> <module 'numpy' from 'C:\\python\\conda3\\envs\\pyfin\\lib\\site- 
> packages\\numpy\\__init__.py'>

var2 = np.arange(10).reshape(2, 5)
print(var2)
# output:
> [[0 1 2 3 4]
> [5 6 7 8 9]]
```

There may be other uses, but these 3 comes to my mind.